# Renovate Automerge

Tags: github, renovate

I want renovate not to auto merge "major" updates of certain dependencies, but it should auto merge other updates from those dependencies.

For example, if I want renovate to auto merge all "minor" and "patch" updates of eslint, but it should not auto merge all the "major" updates to eslint.

How can I define the rules in my renovate json file to comply for this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package rule from the [docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/automerge-configuration/) will automerge all minor and patch updates with a version number greater than 1.0.0.

```
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch"],
      "matchCurrentVersion": "!/^0/",
      "automerge": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in the docs using the regex `!/^0/` doesn't work for all languages. Go versions for example tend to be prefixed with `v`. A better solution is to have a rule that uses the parsed semver. The rule below works for all languages.

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["patch"],
      "matchCurrentVersion": ">= 1.0.0",
      "automerge": true
    }
}
```